# How to auto redirect from one URL to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I would like a little help with `iframe` coding to specifically redirect from one URL to another without the user having to click anything to be redirected.

iframe id="schedulista-widget-00" src="https://www.schedulista.com/schedule/neecostylez?mode=widget&rt_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.neecostylez.com&rt_text=Click+HERE+to+return+to+the+site" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="900px">

Everything works fine except I don't want users to have to click to be redirected and not be able to see the text specifying to "click here". I just want it to be redirected.

I found the below code but I'm not sure where to plug in the details needed to put in order for successful results.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <a id="link" target="_parent" href="outsideDomain.html"></a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById('link').click();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you just flag your own post?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a meta `http-equiv` tag to "refresh" the page to a new url as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/path/to/go/to/file.html">
```

The **content** sets how long to wait until to redirect the user, and the **url** sets where to redirect the user.

Read more about it [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the meta http-equiv tag as k97513 mentioned. You could also use JavaScript as follows.

```
<script>
    window.location = "https://www.google.com";
</script>
```

Just place that in the body tag and replace Google with whatever URL you want to redirect to.